# Meet at WTC 2019 (Wolfram Technology Conference)?

Tags: discussion

@kickert posted an answer [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2525/4999) but I think it should be a separate question.

Anyone attending the Wolfram Technology Conference in Champaign?

Perhaps a meet up?

Comment: Don't forget to upload pictures people :)

Comment: I initially assumed WTC = World Trade Center...

Comment: @ColinMacLaurin Thanks. Local blind spot.

Comment: It was good meeting several of you this week.  Hated to depart early, but glad I missed the snow.  Safe travels.

Comment: @kickert, it wasn't *that* much snow...

Comment: @BrettChampion It was enough to cancel my flight and leave me stranded in Champaign for another day. I wish I missed the snow.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry to hear your flight was cancelled!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hate to hear that.  Hope your travels go smoothly from here.  It was great finally being able to put a face with a name.

Comment: @BrettChampion and kickert, thanks.  Leaving in a couple of hours I hope. I also hope someone will post pictures for Kuba!

Comment: hi @MichaelE2, was great meeting you during the conference. Good to know we have a nearby neighbor in the ATL area!

Answer (score 7):

I am attending the conference! I’ll have a talk, too. Should be a great time :D I have been hoping for a meet-up, too. Currently waiting for my flight :))

[image: StackExchange TableCard]

Comment: They've got a placard for us! When shall we meet?

Comment: Heck... I was there in the afternoon and this tag was just lying around on the table.  Anyone doing a meetup tomorrow?  Maybe if no one is around, I'll just grab the tag, commandeer a table and act all snooty until someone joins me .. the password to join the table is "frobenius". ;)

Comment: @dearN meet at lunch?

Comment: Sure.  I am occupied until 11.30am.  At 11.30, I'll walk to the lunch room entrance.  If the "stackExchange" tag is still around, I'll pick it up as a placard.   Thanks and looking fwd 2 it.  I will stick around outside lunch door until 11.35 and then carry the SE placard with me, into the room.  Can you do the same, if you get there before me?

Answer (score 5):

here is our annual picture taken.[image]

Comment: I believe I know most of these people, but could you put in a list of who's in this picture for reference?

Comment: From left to right:@Edmund, @P. Fonseca, SW, Zviovich, Ricardo de la Cruz, Gil Porter